# bootstrapValidator is not working?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I would like to use bootstrapValidator in my form and i have seen that its not working.

Below is the html code

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="css/bootstrapValidator.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                    <form id="form_login" method="post" action="#">
                    <h2>Log In</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                         <input type="email" name="email" id="loginemail" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address"   tabindex="1">
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" id="loginpassword" maxlength="12" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2">
                                    </div>

                        </div>



                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-theme btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="3"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">Don't have an account? <a href="signin.html" tabindex="3">Register</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<script src="js/validations.js"></script>
```

and below is the jquery code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$('#form_login').bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        loginemail: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The first name is required and cannot be empty'
                }
            }
        },
        loginpassword: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The last name is required and cannot be empty'
                }
            }
        } /* <-- removed unneeded comma */
    } /* <-- added closing brace */
});
    });
```

Since morning I am trying to identify the issue but I m not able to find it yet.
Anyone can suggest or help me to sort out the issue

Comment: Any leads who can help to sort out the issue will be highly appreciated

Comment: You've probably done this, but do you get any console errors with the validator files not being loaded?

Comment: hi, no i have not got any msg. i have checked with alert before $('#form_login').bootstrapValidator({ and after at the end of this. its working.

Comment: i opened validations.js in adobe dream weaver 2015 and there i have seen that when i press $('#form_login'). and I can not see any bootstrapValidator method over there... it means bootstrapvalidator.js is not included properly..

Comment: Did you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149928/using-bootstrapvalidator-ajax-submithandler-does-not-work?rq=1 ? Not exactly what your issue is but maybe that code will help... or this... http://twitterbootstrap.org/bootstrap-form-validation/

Comment: I know how to validate form with JQuery.. as it is mentioned in second example...

Comment: I know how to validate form with JQuery.. as it is mentioned in second example but i would like to do this with JQuery and Bootloader as it is mentioned in first example. but i m following the same method. dont knw where is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Validation element must have 'name' attribute same as 'field' name in plugin initializer, the plugin will be verified according to the name attribute. You have id names in fields validator of bootstrapValidator. Though it is quite old but i may help if some is having trouble getting it right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a input type submit to make bootstrapValidator to work.

Comment: The Op has an input type submit